# Overriding Bulk Delete of Models in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I wrote a custom `delete` method for a model. It appears to work with two caveats.

1. When I enter into the model instance inside the Django Admin and click delete, then the file is deleted from AWS S3 bucket (that was the purpose of overriding the method in the first place). The model itself gets removed as well.
2. If I delete via "Delete Selected" bulk feature, then the file lingers in S3, but the instance gets removed from the list of instances of this type.

It is my understanding that in the bulk delete, a different (queryset) method is invoked.

My question is what is the most effective method of making both single and bulk deletes act the same? Should I be trying to create a custom manager for this model?

The model declaration and delete method:

```
from boto3.session import Session
from django.conf import settings

class Video(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    description=models.TextField(default="")
    creation_date=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    videofile=models.FileField(upload_to='videos/', null=True, verbose_name="")
    tags = TaggableManager()

    actions = ['delete']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + ": " + str(self.videofile)

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        session = Session (settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
        s3_resource = session.resource('s3')
        s3_bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(settings.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME)

        file_path = "media/" + str(self.videofile)
        response = s3_bucket.delete_objects(
            Delete={
                'Objects': [
                    {
                        'Key': file_path
                    }
                ]
            })
        print(file_path)
        print(response)
        super(Video, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Also you don't need to call s3 session manually ( if you set up Storage Backend)
Filefield has delete handler (  self.videofile.delete() )

Comment: Is it supposed to work as is? In my case it leaves the file in-place.

Comment: No, as i already stated in my answer you have to override or create custom action. I was commenting specifically on using of s3 code which you have written that could be replaced with single line if you use proper storage backend ( not really related to question but observation, so that why it is comment)

Comment: How can I do that? I have a storage backend, but it is pretty bare right now.

Comment: https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html#settings

Comment: I believe I have it set up exactly according to the instructions. However, I still do not see how it is possible to make the code do the deletion in one line. If you can explain in more detail, it would be great. I also have ImageFields that would need to be deleted in the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing futile work as bulk delete does not use Model delete method ( [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#topics-db-queries-delete) )

> Keep in mind that this will, whenever possible, be executed purely in
>   SQL, and so the delete() methods of individual object instances will
>   not necessarily be called during the process. If you’ve provided a
>   custom delete() method on a model class and want to ensure that it is
>   called, you will need to “manually” delete instances of that model
>   (e.g., by iterating over a QuerySet and calling delete() on each
>   object individually) rather than using the bulk delete() method of a
>   QuerySet.

Django Admin delete selected objects ***does not call*** Models delete method ( same as **any bulk delete queryset**)

[From Django admin actions documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/)

> Warning
>
> The “delete selected objects” action uses QuerySet.delete() for
>   efficiency reasons, which has an important caveat: your model’s
>   delete() method will not be called.
>
> If you wish to override this behavior, you can **override
>   `ModelAdmin.delete_queryset()`** or write a custom action which does
>   deletion in your preferred manner – for example, by calling
>   Model.delete() for each of the selected items.